# Why does Terraform want to destroy this imported aws_organizations_organizational_unit?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We are attempting to build a state file for recently deployed AWS Organisation resources using Terraform v1.0.9 and aws provider v3.64.2.

The `aws_organizations_organization` was corrected imported with `terraform import aws_organizations_organization.my_organisation [id]`. Terraform doesn't want to destroy the organisation after it is imported.

However, when the unit is imported - `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2 terraform import -config=tf/units/infrastructure -var 'organisation_root=[id]' aws_organizations_organizational_unit.my-ou-infrastructure ou-abc0-ab0cdefg` it appears to import successfully, however on `terraform plan` it wants to destroy the OU and recreate it.

```
# aws_organizations_organizational_unit.my-ou-infrastructure will be destroyed
- resource "aws_organizations_organizational_unit" "my-ou-infrastructure" {
    - accounts  = [] -> null
    - arn       = "arn:aws:organizations::000000000000:ou/o-xxxxx/ou-xxxx-xxxxxx" -> null
    - id        = "ou-xxxx-xxxxxx" -> null
    - name      = "name" -> null
    - parent_id = "id" -> null
    - tags      = {} -> null
  }

...

# module.my_organisation_units.module.my_organisation_unit_infrastructure.aws_organizations_organizational_unit.my-ou-infrastructure will be created
  + resource "aws_organizations_organizational_unit" "my-ou-infrastructure" {
      + accounts  = (known after apply)
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "name"
      + parent_id = "id"
    }

...

Plan: 31 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

Should this be happening? From the docs, importing an OU looks as simple as it gets.

Comment: Looks like different resources... one at the root another under a module

Comment: Thank you. It is my first time using `import`. Looks like I need to use the syntax `terraform import module.foo.aws_instance.bar i-abcd1234` for modules.

Answer (score 1):

We needed to import the resource as a module with `terraform import module.my_organisation_units.module.my_organisation_unit_infrastructure.aws_organizations_organizational_unit.my-ou-infrastructure ou-abc0-ab0cdefg`.